# Trouble with Same Card Being Drawn C++

Tags: c++, random, playing-cards

I am creating a Spades game for my C++ class. I have most of it worked out. However, when I draw a card from the deck, it is the same card the entire run of the program. I cannot figure out how to change the second card and so on back to a random card. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I know most of the code is probably not properly written and there are easier ways to write some areas, but I had to follow certain criteria.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


enum eSuit {H, C, D, S};


struct SSingleCard
{
    int iRank;
    eSuit Suits;
};

struct SDeck
{
    SSingleCard aiDeck[52];
    int iCardIndex;
};

struct SPlayerHand
{
    SSingleCard aiHand[13];
    int iTotalHand;
};

struct SCardDisplay
{
    char cSuit;
    char cRank;
};

void showCard(SSingleCard);



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

cout << "Welcome! This is a 2-Player Version of Spades! You vs. The Computer!";

cout << endl;

cout << "You draw first!";

cout << endl;
char cKeepCard;

SDeck Deck; 

Deck.iCardIndex = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
    {
        Deck.aiDeck[Deck.iCardIndex].iRank = j + 2;
        Deck.aiDeck[Deck.iCardIndex].Suits = eSuit(i);
        Deck.iCardIndex++;

    }
}


srand( time( NULL ) );

for( int i = 0; i < 52; i++ )
{
    int iRandomNumber = ( rand() % 51) + 1; 
    SSingleCard card = Deck.aiDeck[i];
    Deck.aiDeck[i] = Deck.aiDeck[iRandomNumber];
    Deck.aiDeck[iRandomNumber] = card;

}   

do
{
    SPlayerHand sPlayersHand;
    SPlayerHand sComputersHand;

    Deck.iCardIndex = 0;

    cout << "You drew ";

    showCard(Deck.aiDeck[Deck.iCardIndex]);

    cout << "Keep this card? (Y/N)";
    string sDecision;
    cin >> sDecision;

    if(sDecision == "N" || sDecision == "n")
    {
        sPlayersHand.aiHand[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] = Deck.aiDeck[Deck.iCardIndex];;
        cout << "You discarded ";
        showCard(Deck.aiDeck[Deck.iCardIndex]);
        Deck.iCardIndex++;
    } else if (sDecision == "Y" || sDecision == "y") 
    {
        sPlayersHand.aiHand[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] = Deck.aiDeck[Deck.iCardIndex];
        showCard(Deck.aiDeck[Deck.iCardIndex]);
        Deck.iCardIndex++;
        showCard(Deck.aiDeck[14]);
        Deck.iCardIndex++;
        sComputersHand.aiHand[0] = Deck.aiDeck[Deck.iCardIndex];
        Deck.iCardIndex++;

    } else {
        cout << "That input is invalid. Try again." << endl;
    }
}while (Deck.iCardIndex < 52);

std::cin.sync();
std::cin.get();
return 0;
}

void showCard(SSingleCard card)
{

    if( card.iRank >= 2 && card.iRank <=9 )
        cout << card.iRank;
            switch( card.iRank )
            {
                case 10:
                    cout << "T";
                    break;          
                case 11:
                    cout << "J";                
                    break;
                case 12:
                    cout << "Q";                
                    break;
                case 13:
                    cout << "K";                
                    break;
                case 14:
                    cout << "A";                
                    break;
            }

    if( card.Suits >= 0 && card.Suits <= 4 )
            switch( card.Suits )
            {
                case 0:
                    cout << 'C' << endl;                    
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cout << 'D' << endl;                    
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << 'S' << endl;                    
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << 'H' << endl;                    
                    break;
            }
}
```

Comment: The usuall way is to create an array with the same number of elements as your deck has cards. Then you fill each item with it's index. So you have 52 elements, numbered 1-52. Then you go through and randomly swap elements with other elements. To draw a card, you just maintain an index into that (shuffled) array. Each time you extract a card, increment the index. If the index==numberOfCardsInDeck then there are no cards left to draw..

Comment: Evaluate if this is the shortest code you can submit which demonstrates the problem you want to discuss.  What lines might you delete?  Are program input/output necessary or could you hardcode values?  If the problem occurs with 4 suits and 52 cards...can you show it with 1 suit and 2 cards?  *How short a program can you provide us with that pushes you to your first moment of confusion?*  (Note that you can edit your question with the "edit" button...)  http://sscce.org/

Comment: One note: the remark by HostileFork above is not only about submission. This process of *reduction* applies to bug tracking as well; learn to do it, and you will be able to find the bugs yourself!

Answer (score 2):

Line 85:

```
Deck.iCardIndex = 0;
```

This is *inside the loop*. Every time you want to draw a card, you reset the index and start over at the top of the deck.

More generally, you should build up from the simple to the complex, testing at every step. When you had the `Deck` ready, you should have tried dealing a few cards, before putting in the interactive choices and other stuff. Then this bug would have been easier to spot.

Comment: Wow, such an easy error! Thank you so much. I am very grateful. I will try working more carefully next time.